# Visual Studio 2010, PCL, Qt and 32-bit and 64-bit: How?

Tags: windows, qt, installation, 32bit-64bit, point-cloud-library

PCL 1.6 (Point Cloud Library) requires a stack of third-party libraries, including Qt.  For this, they have individual installers for their libraries and Qt 4.8.0 for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit support (yes, I am attempting to avoid building all of these from source).  I require both 32- and 64-bit, separately. It looks like the 32-bit and 64-bit Qt installers write to the same installation folder and I fear that one will simply overwrite the other.  Can I simply redirect the install location, say, `Qt\4.8.0_64\` and `Qt\4.8.0_32\` to differentiate the installs? Will this wreak havoc with paths and registry entries for PCL and my builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. I have QT 4.8 and 5.0.2 on my machine. The environment variable QTDIR points to the ne you want. If you use Visual Studio and the QT addin you can have multiple QT version changeable by the QT options dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Just remember to save this path in "environment variable". and also be careful when you build your project with CMake. Cmake might not find the new path, and you have to change it manually in cmake gui.